# How much to water Raspberries on a drip line?

Tags: watering, drip-system, raspberries

I just put in a drip line today. I only used 1 GPH emitters on the raspberries. Any idea how long I should water them when it dries up this summer? I know it should be 1 to 2 inches a weeks but how do you convert that the GPH on a drip system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 inch of water over a 18" wide area = 1/8 of a cubic foot of water per foot of bed.

A cubic foot is about 8 gallons.

If you are using 1 gallon drippers, then you would want to run it for about 1 hour per week.

---

Expansion:  Rasps like it damp.  Mulch well with wood chips.  Water when the bottom of the wood chips are dry.